# Unable to find resource although file is in classpath

Tags: java, spring, apache-velocity

I have added Apache Velocity 1.7 to my spring 3.2.5.RELEASE application in order to convert html to string and send mail. My spring context is defined below:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine1" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have added the file test.vm in my src/main/resources folder.

The below line is where I'm using the engine:

```
   @Autowired
    @Qualifier("velocityEngine1")
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

public JSONResult uploadFile(MultipartFile file, AppUserDTO appUserDTO){

        String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "test", "UTF-8", null);
        System.out.println(body);

...

}
```

When it execute the method `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString` I get exception:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'test'
```

Comment: what is `swan_asset_overwrite_notification`? should be templateLocation as `test.vm`

Comment: sorry my mistake while writing the question,it is test i have updated my question

Comment: Did you tried `test.vm` instead of test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put [full path with template file](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils&method=mergeTemplateIntoString), in your case

```
 VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "test.vm", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: in case if i have my test.vm in an additional folder such as src/main/resources/template/ do i need to update my bean for the location?

Comment: @user1999453 No, Just use `"/template/test.vm"` when calling `mergeTemplateIntoString`